# Java How use Spring Autowired in SystemInitializer class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a Java Project with `Spring MVC`. 
I need to start TimerTasks already after my application is initialized, so I implemented the `WebApplicationInitializer` Interface and I call it `SystemInitializer`. Inside that class I have a `@Autowired` property, that `@Autowired` property is a `DAO` class.
I need it cause I want to execute some tasks based in recordings from my data base. But that Autowired property is ever null.

```
public class SystemInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Autowired
private DomainResearchDao domainResearchDao;

@Override
public void run() {
    if (this.domainResearchDao != null) {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
    // always here
    else{
       System.out.println("NO OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you marked `DomainResearchDaoImpl` with `@Repository` annotation?

Comment: I think so: @Repository("domainResearchDao")
public class DomainResearchDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, DomainResearch> {...

Comment: `DomainResearchDaoImpl` should also `implements DomainResearchDao`

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Comment: Andremoniy I put the implements  in my code, I just forgot to put here...

Comment: Arif Acar, I will... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `@Autowired` inside of `WebApplicationInitializer`.

Your Beans are not ready (not scanned yet) to be injected. Your Application has no idea what `DomainResearchDao` is at that moment.

Spring can autowire beans only after your application is initialized and all (singletone) instances (`@Component`, `@Service` etc.) are created.

---

If you want to do some job after your application is started, use Spring Event for doing this:

```
@Component
public class DoOnStart{

    @Autowired
    private IYourService service;

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent e) {
        // your CODE
    }

}
```

Just implement this class, no need to autowire it.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that... So how can I do that? I need to start a service  already after my application is initialized, but only once. If I put some code in a @Configuration class, it will be executed only once? Thanks